# Extracting column from comma separated text

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl, csv

I have a long comma-separated delimited file with 20K lines. Here's a sample:

```
"","id","number1","number2","number3","number4","number5","number6","number7"
"1","MRTAT_1of3.RTS",17.1464602742708,17.1796255746079,17.1132949739337,0.996138996138996,-0.0055810322632996,1,1
"2","MRTAT_2of3.RTS",3.88270908946253,6.13558056235995,1.62983761656512,0.265637065637066,-1.91247162787182,0.718084341158075,1
"3","MRTAT_3of3.RTS",3.87323328936623,1.22711611247199,6.51935046626046,5.31274131274131,2.40945646701554,0.676814519398334,1
```

I want to print like the columns with id, number4, number5 and number 6 with tab-delimited setting the condition number4 is greater than 4.0. Here's some sample output:

```
id         number4           number5           number6
MRTAT_3of3.RTS 5.31274131274131  2.40945646701554  0.676814519398334
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk -F , -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 || $6 > 4 {print $1, $6, $7, $8}' input.txt
```

Comment: should be `{print $2, $6, $7, $8}`

Answer (score 4):

I agree that  awk is the best solution. You *can* do this just in bash with a couple of other tools:

```
cut -d , -f 2,6,7,8 filename | {
    read header
    tr , $'\t' <<< "$header"
    while IFS=, read -r id num4 num5 num6; do
        # bash can only do integer arithmetic
        if [[ $(bc <<< "$num4 >= 4.0") = 1 ]]; then
           printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$id" "$num4" "$num5" "$num6"
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Really can't beat the awk script above, but here's a ruby solution,

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

puts "id\tnumber4\tnumber5\tnumber6"

ARGF.each_line do |line|
  arr = line.split(',')
  puts "#{arr[1]}\t#{arr[5]}\t#{arr[6]}\t#{arr[7]}" if arr[5].to_f > 4.0
end
```

To use the script call it with the filename or pipe the file into it.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F, -le '$, = "\t"; print @F[1,5,6,7] if $F[5] > 4 || $. == 1' file
```

> `-F,` specifies the pattern to split on. `-F` implicitly sets `-a`
>
> `-a` turns on autosplit mode when used with a `-n`. An implicit split command to the `@F` array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the `-n`. `-a` implicitly sets `-n`
>
> `-n` causes Perl to assume the loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`
>
> `-l` enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps the input record separator (`\n`). Second, it assigns the output record separator to `\n`.
>
> `-e` used to enter one line of program

So, `perl -F, -le '$, = "\t"; print @F[1,5,6,7] if $F[5] > 4 || $. == 1'` do something like this:

```
use English;

$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;

while (<>) { # iterate over each line of the each file
    chomp;
    @F = split(',');
    $OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR = "\t";
    print @F[1,5,6,7] if $F[5] > 4 || $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER == 1;
}
```

Comment: To add value to your answer please could you take a few moments to explain how it works.

Comment: @roaima, ok. one moment.

Comment: @roaima, done. what do you think?